# Loading a Flat File in Informatica 9.5

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have three sources ie. Flat Files(4 Records),Oracle(3 Records) and Netezza(5 Records). I want 12 Records in my target table which is a flat file. How to achieve this via Informatica 9.5? I know we can use Joiner Transformation for joining heterogeneos records but i am not sure about the join conditions in the Joiner. Pls advise on the same

Comment: From your question, it seems you want to **union** the sources rather than join. Are the structures of the sources similar? can you provide the layout of your sources?

Comment: the structures of the sources are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Union transformation. First drag the required ports from any one of the sources to the Union trf. Now, create 3 groups in the Union transformation. This will create 3 sets of input ports. Now connect the ports from other two sources to the remaining input groups of the Union transformation.

There will one set of output ports, which you can connect to the target definition (flat file).

Comment: Thanks for the info ..it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` transformation, if the structure of the three sources are same.

Otherwise we need to go for joiner transformation with one of the matching columns in all three sources and do a full outer join.